# Receiving Bad Interpreter: Permission Denied when Running Bash Script in Termux but not when running with "bash"

Tags: bash, termux

Receiving Bad Interpreter:  Permission Denied when Running Bash Script in Termux but not when running with "bash".

Notes:

- for troubleshooting purposes both bash and the script set to chmod 777.
- chsh to bash
- ensured Termux bash first in export PATH variable
- shebang in script with absolute path to bash

Am I missing something?

(Finally figured out how to edit on mobile)

Script:

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/b2/faa78c1ab928d2b2c634c8b41ff1181f0abdd9adf9193211bd606ffa57e2/cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz
```

Commands:
`./getcrypt.sh`.
Permission Denied

```
bash get-crypt.sh
```

Works

Exact Error Message:
`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

Purpose:
Just uses wget to download a cryptography module for python.  Copying and pasting url into terminal on mobile messed up the URL, so I put it into a one-line script.

Troubleshooting:

```
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash ./getcrypt.sh

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash: ./getcrypt.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 1) please show your script 2) show us the way you invoke it in your comand line

Comment: #!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash

wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/b2/faa78c1ab928d2b2c634c8b41ff1181f0abdd9adf9193211bd606ffa57e2/cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz

Comment: ./get-crypt.sh doesn't work-Error

Comment: Edit your question and properly format your code, don't post this in the comments

Comment: bash get-crypt.sh works

Comment: Also - show the exact error message you get

Comment: See : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: in your command line, what does `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash ./getcrypt.sh` do ?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/issues/269) apparently. Users in the github thread solved this by updating their ROMs

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and thorough answer!!!  I couldn't type fast enough before you solved it.  ;)

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Comment: I was ruling out a permissions issue. Has been remedied. I appreciate the heads up though!